# Помогите фиксануть в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Господа, такая проблема. Когда убираю слеш на конце, возникает циклическая переадресация.

**Взял с интернета данные т.к. в htaccess не шарю**

Вот фрагмент

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Также есть проблема, что когда убираю .php на конце файла, то сайт перестает отличать каталоги от файлов..например, в корне есть файл **fail.php** и каталог **fail**. Если перейти по **site.ru/fail** то будет ошибка 500 вроде.

Вот фрагмент

```
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Также есть правила на подобии таких

```
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)\.php$ /item_info?id=$1  [L]
```

Они работают, но я думаю, что если Вы что то посоветуете изменить, то они работать не будут ))

Буду очень признателен за развернутый ответ т.к. сокращенный я врядли пойму :)

Comment: не используйте 301, пока не будете уверены, что всё корректно) Используйте 302

Comment: @vp_arth вряд ли я буду уверен, что все корректно..зная, что я ничего не знаю в htaccess..вот )

Comment: Тем более, просто 301 мешает прямо в процессе разбирательства. Браузер запоминает некорректные редиректы и исправление .htaccess потом не помогает.

Comment: @vp_arth ну насчет этого я знаю..достаточно сбросить сохраненку для сайта за Н время или за все время.. А с 302 не запоминается ?

Comment: 302 - временный редирект на один раз, 301 - постоянный. Попробуйте добавить в вопрос информацию о том, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: @vp_arth дык там указано, чего я хочу добиться..указаны проблемы, которые нужно подсказать как решить )

Comment: Вам нужно убрать концевые / и .php, разрешая конфликт папки и скрипта в пользу скрипта, верно?

Comment: @vp_arth Да, верно